# Redirect all URLs to no-www https

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

I would like to forward all requests to a domain via .htaccess.

Everything to: https://domain.tdl

- No-www
- https

I have tried many spelling, but it has not worked for completely.

Comment: Show what you tried as well

Answer (score 2):

I think the following single set of rule-set should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You must also consider `off` and `!www.`, either in a separate rule or with an appropriate regex for HTTP_HOST.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Why? The above would work if either of those conditions is true, i.e., access over `http` or the `HTTP_HOST` starts with _www_.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `OR` flag, sorry.